# How to get object from PK inside Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Inside django template, I would like to get object's name using object's pk. For instance, given that I have pk of object from class `A`, I would like to do something like the following:

```
{{ A.objects.get(pk=A_pk).name }}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: That's not possible, you should be doing that in your views.py: `a = A.objects.get(pl=A_pk)` then show it in your template: `{{ a.name }}`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the docs on [The Django Template Language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/):

[Accessing method calls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#accessing-method-calls):

> Because Django intentionally limits the amount of logic processing available in the template language, it is not possible to pass arguments to method calls accessed from within templates. Data should be calculated in views, then passed to templates for display.

So you see, you should be calculating this in your `views.py:`

```
def my_view(request, A_pk):
    ...     
    a = A.objects.get(pk=A_pk)    
    ...
    return render_to_response('myapp/mytemplate.html', {'a': a})
```

And in your template:

```
{{ a.name }}
{{ a.some_field }}
{{ a.some_other_field }}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can add your own tag if you want to. Like this:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_obj(pk, attr):
    obj = getattr(A.objects.get(pk=int(pk)), attr)
    return obj
```

Then load tag in your template

```
{% load get_obj from your_module %}
```

and use it

```
{% get_obj "A_pk" "name" %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in Django. [From the docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#accessing-method-calls)

> Because Django intentionally limits the amount of logic processing available in the template language, it is not possible to pass arguments to method calls accessed from within templates. Data should be calculated in views, then passed to templates for display.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you're trying to accomplish but you should figure out how you can achieve your desired outcome in the view and send the variable or object to the template.

Answer (score 0):

1. create folder named 'templatetags' inside the module.
2. create 'anyname.py' inside the templatetags

anyname.py

```
from django import template
from Clients.models import Client
register = template.Library()
@register.filter
def get_client_name(pk, attr):
    obj = getattr(Client.objects.get(id=pk),attr)
    return obj
```

now in the template add

```
{% load get_client_name from anyname %}
{{project.Client_id|get_client_name:'Name_of_client' }}
```

also you can check
[django documentation on custom tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)