# Django: how to get a model instance by id within a template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-template-filters

Just a quick question - I was wondering if it were possible to return a model instance by id within a template e.g.,

If I had a list of comments associated to posts by the post Id, and did something like:

```
{% for comment in comments %}

  {{ request.post.get_by_id(id == comment.object_id).title }}

{% endfor %}
```

I'm working within a tags.py "pseudo-view" using the following:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('blog/frame/latest_comments.html')
def show_latest_comments(count=5):
    latest_comments = Comment.objects.all()[:count]

    return { 'latest_comments': latest_comments}
```

Should I work within the tags.py file to maybe loop over the latest_comments object and extract everything I need, including the blog post it is associated to and then dump this in the context as a new dictionary...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get object from PK inside Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866952/how-to-get-object-from-pk-inside-django-template)

Comment: @SławomirLenart Not quite the same as I am wanting to reference across models - so reference the Post model associated to the id which is stored when a new comment is made, that comment "object_id" should then be referenced against the Post model with the same Id. I think I will work within the tags.py file for this. I'll leave this question up incase anyone does have a working method.

Comment: follow genry's response there. Remember, basically data should be prepared in views.

Comment: Yep. I've managed to get what I want out using a loop. Worried about loading times now tho.

Comment: Pretty sure you're [reinventing the wheel](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/packages.html#module-mezzanine.generic.templatetags.comment_tags).

Comment: @Melvyn Perhaps, but I think you're overlooking the fact that [I have no idea what I'm doing](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/62/8d/61/628d61bdc24738e73ce54001e25bec15--business-google-plan.jpg)